# Cannot display date with react-datepicker with react-hooks-forms on screen

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, next.js, react-datepicker, react-hook-form

I am making a form in **next.js** where I would be storing date along with other fields.

I'm using **react-form-hooks** and **react-datepicker**

**Problem:** when I click submit, I can see the date entry in console.log but cannot see the selected date in date input. pls refer screenshot for detail
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvJWL.png)

I follow the example given in https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx where they are also using react-datepicker with react-hooks-forms

**desired result:** when i select date, date should appear in date input box eg: 09/08/2020

below is the code i have written. pls help , thanks

```
import Head from "next/head";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const Form = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  const [selectedDate, setselectedDate] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/2.14.1/react-datepicker.min.css"
        />
      </Head>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <section>
          <label>Created Date</label>
          <Controller
            as={DatePicker}
            control={control}
            valueName="selected"
            selected={selectedDate}
            onChange={(date) => setselectedDate(date)}
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
            placeholderText="Select Date"
            name="DatePicker"
            defaultValue={null}
          />
          {/* <DatePicker
            selected={selectedDate}
            onChange={(date) => setselectedDate(date)}
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
            placeholderText="Select Date"
          /> */}
        </section>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, your problem is on `onChange` prop. If the `valueName` prop is setted as `selected`, `onChange` function must returns `selected` like this:

```
onChange={([selected]) => {
   setselectedDate(selected);
   return selected;
}}
```

So your `DatePicker` becomes:

```
<Controller
   as={DatePicker}
   control={control}
   valueName="selected"
   selected={selectedDate}
   onChange={([selected]) => {
      setselectedDate(selected);
      return selected;
   }}
   dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
   placeholderText="Select Date"
   name="DatePicker"
   defaultValue={null}
/>
```

Not only but, despite you already setted a dateFormat in `DatePicker` element, to get data in a particular format you need to re-format data comes from `form`. Since react-hooks-forms `DatePicker` uses `moment` for date, I have used `moment` to format output date.

So `onSubmit` function becames:

```
import moment from "moment";
...
const onSubmit = (data) => {
   console.log(moment(selectedDate).format("DD/MM/yyyy"));
};
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-but7g?file=/src/index.js) codesandbox modified that shows what I have done.

Comment: It doesn't work for me still, I have literally copy-pasted your solution but it still won't show the selected date in my date input box.

But I would like to say my issue wasn't the output in console.log but the fact that the selected date won't appear in the date input box. like when you select any date via date picker, the selected date should appear in the date input box, in my case, it doesn't, placeholder remains and doesn't disappear and when I clicked submit, the date gets outputted.

Comment: Ciao, I found your problem. I modified my answer and codesandbox example.

Comment: Hey, still isnt working, I have created a codesandbox and pasted the code u have provided, the thing is I have checked the link u provided it works fine there, but doesn't work in my code, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-err-date-picker-rhcig?file=/src/App.js here is the link to my codesandbox pls have a look at the code.

Comment: Oh, I found why your example doesn't work. We are using different react-hook-form version! In your codesandbox  you are using v. 6.3.1 . In my codesandbox I use v. 5.5.1 . I just changed version in your example and all it worked. Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-err-date-picker-op6zu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks, man, it worked! cant believe it was version issue. Are you aware of any reason as it why it isn't working in the latest version but in older versions?

Comment: No, I really don't know. Maybe you found a bug on last react-hook-form version who knows... I watched my code and your code for 30 minutes to undestand that the problem was on version. Anyway, problem solved! Have a nice day :)